# Determine how many days in a given month

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I am doing some calculations based on no of days in a given month,

*Determine current Year Month*

```
Date date = new Date();
Year = YearFormat.format(date);
Month = MonthFormat.format(date);
```

*Determine how many days in the current month*

```
int year = Integer.valueOf(Year);
int month = Integer.valueOf(Month);
Calendar calendarD = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
int noOfDaysOfMonth = calendarD.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

*Problem*

`noOfDaysOfMonth` seems not giving me the correct no of days.

For example `year = 2018 , month = 8` gave me `30` which I expect `31`

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalDate`...

Comment: Maybe an off-by-one. If the month starts with 0, month=8 would be September with 30 days. And also: use LocalDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LengthOfMonth` method is for that. Besides, I think `Calendar` API shouldn't be used anymore.  It is already old.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2019, 6, 20);
int days = date.lengthOfMonth();
```

---

[5 Reasons Why Java's old Date and Calendar API was Bad](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/5-reasons-why-javas-old-date-and-Calendar-API-bad.html)

Answer (score 6):

## `LocalDate::lengthOfMonth`

If you use Java 8, you can access the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API.

Specifically, the [`LocalDate::lengthOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#lengthOfMonth()) method.

```
int length = LocalDate.now().lengthOfMonth();
```

Comment: Correct answer. Also, if working with months as a whole, the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class may be useful.  `YearMonth.now().lengthOfMonth()`

Comment: In other works, if your target API level is > 25, then you can use this. That is only 39% of the market share at the time of posting this comment...

Answer (score 3):

month starts with 0 = january; month = 8 ist september and september have just 30 days.

To avoid this use `Calendar.AUGUST` for exaxmple instead of 8.